# Should I delete my build up comments after an answer has been accepted?

Tags: discussion, comments

I am seeing a behavior where someone (maybe with higher reputation points) delete their comments after the answer has been accepted or their comments served their purpose, for example: putting the author of the answer to right direction. Is it okay to do so?

I personally believe one should not delete comments, because it might help someone later to get ideas from an answer. For example, by comments (discussions with others) let’s say I came up with some cool solution; when initially I was be wrong or going to the wrong direction, but those comments helped me to build it up. Maybe someday my answer can become outdated. If someone reads the answer with comments, they might suggest an even better/updated answer.

*But, I am facing an issue where someone who helped me build up the answer, deleted his/her comments, and now my comments do not make any sense.*

So, what should be my expected behavior? Delete those build up comments?

Comment: Meh, comments are of little value after the dust has settled. It shouldn't matter much whether keep them or delete them as all pertinent information *of lasting value* should be present in the question and answer.

Comment: Related: [Joel wants to comments go away after 7 days (at 50 min 50 secs)](https://unfiltered.tv/#/detail/48de2202be5c4674b471b51b4b9b289b)

Comment: @PeterMortensen: He can write a feature request meta post, like all the rest of us.  Or maybe post a tweet.

Comment: If you think your comments have a value then do an edit to include the valuable parts of the comments in the answer and then delete the comments.

Comment: @RobertHarvey so that it can get implemented in 6 - 8 weeks XD XD XD

Comment: I think in this situation it would make sense to delete them. I would have been more worried about the other way: deleting your comments while the others are still there and wouldn't make sense anymore, as you can only delete your own comments.

Comment: @marsze You could flag those reactions that make no sense without your comments as "no longer needed" - if that is the case (i.e. if the whole exchange - your comments and the reactions - is obsolete, delete yours and flag the rest).

Comment: @JiriTousek True, I didn't even know this option existed. To me a flag item usually conveys the meaning of flag as "rude or illegal" only, so I never even looked if there were other available options. Plus, you can only flag a limited number of comments (although you probably won't exceed it).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If your comments no longer have any value, delete them.

This applies if

- they no longer make sense because other comments have been deleted
- the information asked for in the comment has been provided

You can always include the information from your comments in your answer, assuming you write one and that information makes sense there. You can also encourage the OP to add the information in comments into the question where it makes sense to do so.

Comments are ephemeral, if they are flagged they may well get deleted and as you've seen those who write comments often delete them too.

Comment: I prefer not to delete the comments until all the relevant information is incorporated in the post. If you have editor privileges, you can do it yourself.

Comment: Some comments are still useful. They may not need to be directly in the question, or the answer, but provide a trail and clues to alternative routes. That is, the question and answer themselves may not be precisely what the reader needs, but reading some comments could point to alternative approaches or resources, or even just a prompt to improve their search terms.

Comment: @AndyG some comments, especially highly upvoted ones, survive far longer than the average comment.

Comment: "You can also encourage the OP to add the information in comments into the question where it makes sense to do so" ... or edit it into the post yourself, if the comment was left by OP.

Comment: @AndyG Sometimes, yes. But mostly they're just a disorganised noisy mess. In theory all comments should eventually either be edited into posts or removed (in practice this doesn't always work so well).

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, mostly noise, but not all noise. I am trying to dissuade the urge to delete all comments *just because*.

Comment: @AndyG but not keep all comments *just because* either.